# How can I know which text document map to which ID

Tags: sequence, key-value, mahout

I am learning Mahout with 'Mahou in Action' and right now I am in chapter 8. I just downloaded the Reuters-21578 file and use the following commands to convert all the documents to SequenceFile:

```
bin/mahout seqdirectory -c UTF-8
-i examples/reuters-extracted/ -o reuters-seqfiles
```

and I got chunk-0 in the 'reuters-seqfiles' folder.

My question is: How can I know which document has been assigned to which ID in this sequence file?

Comment: Probably the IDs are assigned *sequentially*.

Comment: Oh, and where is [tag:cluster-analysis] in this question? That is a specific type of statistical analysis, but your question is about loading data into mahout. Removing the tag.